# Mathematics and Grammar

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

I am reading  "Linear Algebra done right" Book (3rd) edition by Axler. I am trying to understand the following statement :
"An addition on a set V is a function that assigns an element u+v ∈ V to each pair of elements u,v ∈ V" 
I am not a native English speaker, therefore, I am confused by the use of the preposition "addition on a set" shouldn't be an addition in a set ? also the word "assigns" seems to me as "replaces".

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: "On" or "in" is fine and interchangeable here.  "Replaces" wouldn't be quite right, since when we replace something one thing has to go away:  neither $u$ nor $v$ disappear here.

Comment: An operation is done *on* a given set, even if it takes place *in* the given set. Example: A group $G$ *acts on a set* $X$, not in a set $X$.

Comment: Usually, in math, we use the term [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)): "an operator is generally a mapping (a *function*) that acts **on** the elements of a space (a set $X$) to produce other elements of the same space ($X$)." Thus, addition is an *operation* defined on a set $V$ that assigns to every pair $u,v$ of elements of $V$ an element of $V$.

Comment: I think "on" is more correct since "addition" is a particular type of "function", and on usually speaks of a "function on a set" rather than a "function in a set". Also, "assign" is the action of the function, so that's normal as well; it indicates $(u,v)\mapsto u+v$.

Comment: An employer can *assign* a job to an employee: that person is *associated* with the job. If the employer *replaces* the employee with someone else, then he or she is gone!

Answer (score 4):

One of the lessons that was pounded into me while trying to learn Russian and German (as a native English speaker) is that prepositions are a royal pain in the ass.  In this case, I think that you would be understood if you said either "addition on" or "addition in" $V$.

That being said, there are subtle reasons that "on" might be slightly preferable.  One way of thinking of binary relations (addition, multiplication, etc) is as functions with a domain consisting of the two-fold Cartesian product of the set.  That is, addition is a function
$$ + : V\times V \to V. $$
Addition can be defined *on* this Cartesian product, thus as a shorthand, it makes sense to say "addition on $V$."

Moreover, as others have pointed out in the comments, we often think of groups acting on other sets.  In a really abstract way, we can think of an underlying groug acting on $V$ to give vector addition.  I wouldn't worry too much about such details—at least, not until you have taken a few courses in modern or abstract algebra—but you might eventually be able to make some sense of it.

All of that being said, if I really wanted to emphasize that a set is closed under an operation, I might be tempted to say that the operation is defined "in" a set.

Long story short:  Either preposition is fine.  There are subtle distinctions to the native ear.  "On" is probably slightly preferable in most situations.